# Proper way to close style element in Nextjs JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jsx

I am trying to add styling inside a jsx component.

The compiler gives an error message for the code below.

```
import Card from "./card";

export default function CardRow(){
  return(
    <>
      <div>
        <Card></Card>
        <Card></Card>
        <Card></Card>
      </div>

      <style jsx>`
        div {
          display: flex
        }
      `
      </style>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Error: 
  x Expected '}', got ':'
    ,----
 14 | display: flex
    :        ^
    `----
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add styles in the component, you have to start and end with the following:

Start:

```
<style jsx>{`
```

End:

```
`}</style>
```

You need to wrap the whole style with {``} braces.